# config file is not one of the known types

Tags: astar

I am following [How to setup zombienet for XCM testing](https://docs.astar.network/docs/builder-guides/leverage_parachains/zombienet) tutorial. But faced error [hear](https://docs.astar.network/docs/builder-guides/leverage_parachains/zombienet#start-the-zombienet-with-the-configuration-file). Any suggestion would help a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the recent releases of `zombienet`, this error will be thrown if config file starts with a comment.

Just remove the comment and it should work just fine.